# mouse wheel click bindings in python issue

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, mousewheel

In windows, this section of code works fine for leftclicks and rightclicks, but will never register a mouse wheel click.  If I change a call for a leftclick or rightclick that works to a call for a wheel click binding, it never registers. What am I missing?

```
    if self.leftclick != None:
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: self.leftclick(x, self.leftclickparas))
    if self.rightclick != None:
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-3>', lambda x: self.rightclick(x, self.rightclickparas))
    if self.wheelclick != None:
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-2>', lambda x: self.wheelclick(x, self.wheelclickparas))
```

Comment: Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: why bind only when clicked? that bind works the whole time anyways until You unbind. so You can easily remove those if statements unless it is something very specific but even then no point of using those if statements

Comment: [I could not reproduce your issue](https://replit.com/@henry43679/stack-67007849)